# No audio after phone call ends

Tags: iphone

How to resume audio after the phone call ends.

Here is my code but it is not working don't know why

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <InfoDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

In m file

```
-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer;
{

}
-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer;

{
   [self.audioPlayer play];
   }
```

Any ideas what is it i m doing wrong or missing from code.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your audio was stopped (did you call `[self.audioPlayer stop]`?) you may have to call `[self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay]` before calling `play` again.

I believe what you ought to do is the following:

```
-(void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer;
{
    [self.audioPlayer pause];
}

-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer;
{
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
```

In my experience, if you call `stop` you then must call `prepareToPlay` before you can call `play` again.

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you may need to handle interruptions via the AudioSession directly.

Your app should initialize the AudioSession, something like this:

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, AudioInterruptionListener, NULL);
```

Then, implement `AudioInterruptionListener` outside your `@implementation`/`@end` block, something like this:

```
#define kAudioEndInterruption   @"AudioEndInterruptionNotification"
#define kAudioBeginInterruption @"AudioBeginInterruptionNotification"

void AudioInterruptionListener (
                             void     *inClientData,
                             UInt32   inInterruptionState
                             )
{
    NSString *notificationName = nil;
    switch (inInterruptionState) {
        case kAudioSessionEndInterruption:
            notificationName = kAudioEndInterruption;
            break;

        case kAudioSessionBeginInterruption:
            notificationName = kAudioBeginInterruption;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (notificationName) {
        NSNotification *notice = [NSNotification notificationWithName:notificationName object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notice];
    }
}
```

Back in your Objective-C, you'll need to listen for the notifications that this code may post, something like this:

```
// Listen for audio interruption begin/end
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(beginAudioInterruption:) 
                                             name:kAudioBeginInterruption object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(endAudioInterruption:) 
                                             name:kAudioEndInterruption object:nil];
```

And:

```
-(void)beginAudioInterruption:(id)context
{
    [self.audioPlayer pause];
}

-(void)endAudioInterruption:(id)context
{
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
```

Give that a whirl. :-)

Comment: Because of the phone call audio gets paused by itself and when phone call ends no audio afterwards.

Comment: Right. So I think _you_ need to pause the audio in `audioPlayerBeginInterruption`. The phone call is causing your audio to _stop_. You want to _pause_ it yourself, so you can restart it when the interruption is over.

Comment: There is an alternative, which is to define a callback for the audio session, which you'll implement in C, not Objective-C. See my edited answer.